# mmenu jQuery plugin doesn't display a button to open menu

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I installed this plugin http://mmenu.frebsite.nl into my Wordpress driven website and I can see in the HTML that it moved the menu and is active, but I cannot seem to get it to display the button to click which will open and close the menu. I've looked through the HTML to see if its being hidden by other elements, but I can't seem to find it.

http://www.mydetroitjewishdirectory.com/

JQuery

```
 jQuery("nav#nav-menu").mmenu();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually create the object that will open and close the menu. The object must be an 'a' tag and the link (href part) must be the id of your menu:

```
//Menu
<ul id="my-menu" class="nav top-nav cf">
  <li>Menu item 1</li>
  <li>Menu item 2</li>
  <li>Menu item 3</li>
</ul>

//Link to open menu, this can be wherever you like
<a href="#my-menu">Open the menu</a>
```

Check out the website for more info: [website](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorial/open-and-close-the-menu.html)

Comment: This worked for me as even with the latest plugin's `.js` files the menu opener object is not automatically added as suggested by other posters...

Answer (score 0):

That is true in the older version. According to documentation this should be applied by the plugin. Anyone else have this issue.

[Screenshot of documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7f9D.png)

Comment: It's better to quote relevant pieces and then link out to the source in answers. That way it's still a good answer if (when) the source changes.